# Spring Data JPA self join query giving unexpected result

Tags: spring-data-jpa, self-join

I have a mysql database table 'Faculties' like below,

[image]

My entity class (FacultyEntity) is as below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Faculty_Id")
private Integer facultyId;

@Column(name = "Faculty_Name", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String facultyName;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "HOD_ID", nullable = true)
private FacultyEntity hodId;
```

I want to display the result in my application sorted by HOD's and and then faculties. This is what I've tried

```
@Query("from FacultyEntity f ORDER BY f.hodId.facultyName, f.facultyName")
```

But I'm getting total 4 rows sorted like this. I think it is because of the null value in the HOD_ID column, But I'm not sure. I'm newbie here.

[image]

The expected result will be

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `f.hodId` in the query, it implicitly translates to inner join, which eliminates the two rows with `null` in `HOD_Id` column.

Try this instead

```
@Query("from FacultyEntity f left join f.hodId hod ORDER BY hod.facultyName, f.facultyName")
```

Comment: Hi Predrag, thanks for your quick reply. it looks like the result is not sorted properly, and I'm not able to read the result in model class object. getting casting error.

Comment: Well, you can't really order them like that, because faculties A and B don't have HOD. You would have to write a custom query to display results in that manner.

Comment: I don't have much idea how to write a custom query to get the result in my model object. I've faced errors while trying custom queries. Can you please help me to write a custom query.
 I've solved this issue by writing an algorithm in java to sort it as per my requirement. But I think it is not the right way to do this.